# Links da página abaixo do link do site no google

Tags: google

Estou com uma dúvida com esses tipos de links abaixo: [image: Links abaixo do link do google]

Me parece ou já ouvi falar que são exibidas assim por conta das ID's das SECTIONS do site, mas o bem é um single page com as SECTIONS bem definidas mas não acho como fazer. Não se isso tem um nome, ou uma técnica específica.

Se puderem dar uma mão, ficaria agradecido.